# L3VPN without route target?

Tags: mpls-vpn

i'm learning L3VPN by myself and route target did confused me a lot. I have a question that i can not find the answer. The question is: 
Does L3VPN work without route target ? 
I have this question because i saw this happened in real life.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L3VPN has to have their PE (label edge routes) configured with RD, route-target import/export in particular VRFs. That's only for purpose of control plane.

To make it clear, let me make brief explanation of RD and route-target.

**route distinguisher (RD)** is used in order discern which prefix belongs to which customer. As you probably know from your own studies, same prefix can be used by multiple customers. E.g. 192.168.0.0/24 can use customer A and also customer B inside their LANs.

You have to be aware that The VPNV4 family itself doesn’t run in a VRF. 
So purpose of RD is only to make IPv4 prefixes globally unique, when BGP advertise NLRI to each other.

It's 8 bytes long field.
See it below in blue box.

[image: Wireshark capture]

**Router-target import/export** is necessary to determine which prefix belongs to which VRF (customer). So when BGP sending update, also include extended community depends on route-target export.

And when particular PE router received that BGP update. He can easily recognize to which VRF prefix belongs, depends on route-target import.

For above image from Wireshark, extended community has been included by PE router (10.0.0.3) depends on route-target export (red box). And will be included into appropriate VRF by another PE router (10.0.0.4) once he received that update, thanks to route-target import.

When you will be familiar enough with above. You can study more advance features, like route leaking between routing tables, etc...

**I created simple MPLS network, so we can make some practical examples.**

(Topology contains only one customer CUST_A)
[image]

When configuration of VRF for CUST_A is following on both PE routers:

```
PE_1#sh run | s ip vrf CUST_A
ip vrf CUST_A
 rd 10:10
 route-target export 10:10
 route-target import 10:10
PE_1#

PE_2#sh run | s ip vrf CUST_A
ip vrf CUST_A
 rd 10:10
 route-target export 10:10
 route-target import 10:10
```

CE_2 router has network 192.168.0.0/24 known from CE_1 in his routing table.

```
CE_2#sh ip ro | b Gateway
Gateway of last resort is not set

     10.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 2 subnets
C       10.4.6.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
B       10.3.5.0 [20/0] via 10.4.6.1, 00:48:52
B    192.168.0.0/24 [20/0] via 10.4.6.1, 00:48:52
C    192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback0
CE_2#
```

In next example I will remove route-target import from particular VRF configuration of CUST_A on PE_2 (R4 in topology) router.

```
PE_2(config)#ip vrf CUST_A
PE_2(config-vrf)#no route-target import 10:10
PE_2(config-vrf)#
```

I can't see prefix 192.168.0.0/24 in BGP VPNV4 table of PE_2 and in routing table of CE_2 router as well.

```
PE_2#sh bgp vpnv4 unicast all
BGP table version is 23, local router ID is 10.0.0.4
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
Route Distinguisher: 10:10 (default for vrf CUST_A)
r> 10.4.6.0/30      10.4.6.2                 0             0 200 ?
*> 192.168.1.0      10.4.6.2                 0             0 200 ?
PE_2#

CE_2#sh ip ro | b Gateway
Gateway of last resort is not set

     10.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       10.4.6.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C    192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback0
CE_2#
```

Even if it's advertised from PE_1 (route R3 in topology) router correctly (with correct RD and RT in NLRI):

```
PE_1#sh bgp vpnv4 unicast all neighbors 10.0.0.4 advertised-routes | b Network
   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
Route Distinguisher: 10:10 (default for vrf CUST_A)
r> 10.3.5.0/30      10.3.5.2                 0             0 100 ?
*> 192.168.0.0      10.3.5.2                 0             0 100 ?

Total number of prefixes 2
PE_1#
```

I can do more examples, but I hope it's clear enough now.
Hope it helps.

Feel free to drop a comment in case of any misunderstanding.

Comment: so that's mean L3VPN can not work without Route target @Daniel Blazek

Comment: no L3vpn cannot work without route-target. Without RT the VRF rib will not be populated with any routes received from remote site. They will just end up in vpnv4 table of BGP in global VRF , but would never make it to the VRF RIB